# Java Thread doesn't seem to run properly

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, chat, runnable

This is the first time i'm asking a question here at stack overflow so bear with me.
I'll try to keep this brief.

I'm writing a simple client socket android application.
The server I'm connecting to has a chat robot named Alice.
I have managed to connect to the server and I receive the message "Hello from alice" but then the thread seems to stop because I'm not receiving any more messages.

Here is some code:

```
    @Override
public void run() {

    try 
    {
        while (true)
        {
        String _input = _rd.readLine();
        if (_input != null)
        {
        _field.append("Alice : "+ _input+"\n");
        }
        else
        {
            _field.append("null");
        }
            sleep(50);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you can see I have attempted to troubleshoot my code by appending "null" even if I don't receive a message, however this is neither shown in my EditText.

I call `.start()` from my main Activity class when the user presses a button.

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            setContentView(R.layout.second);
            InitiateSecondFrame();  

            _cs = new ClientSocket();
            String _check = _cs.EstablishConnection(_host.getText().toString(),
                    Integer.parseInt(_port.getText().toString()),
                    (EditText)findViewById(R.id.historyField));

            _cs.start();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), _check, 100).show();
            SaveHostPort(_host.getText().toString(), _port.getText().toString());                           
        }
    });
```

The `ClientSocket` class is extended by Thread and implements Runnable, I've also tried just extending or implementing.
I do not get any error message at all.
I hope the information I have given is enough for you to realize what's wrong.
Remember I'm new at multithreading and sockets so I might have missed something fundamental.

Comment: I understand what's happening now, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_rd.readLine();
```

is your problem here.  It will block and wait forever for input from the remote system, and will only return the content received when it detects a newline character from the remote system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what are my alternatives if I want to continuously check if the server has sent me a message?

Comment: You already do that: readLine blocks until a line is received.

Comment: get into the habit of using the available() method on the input stream from the remote system.  It will let you know how many bytes are available on the stream for reading, 0 implies there is no data on the remote side.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, here's how you start a thread:

```
Runnable runnable = new MyRunnableClass(); // has the run() method
new Thread(runnable).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

The thread is not stopped. It's just waiting for a message to come. `_rd.readLine()` will block until some line (ending with a newline char) is read, or until the connection ends. So If Alice keeps the connection open and doesn't send anything, readLine will block forever, and your "null" messages won't ever be printed.

Comment: So, does that mean my issue is mostly server side?

Comment: Not sure if the server-side has any issue. Chatting usually means some kind of conversation: Alice told you "Hello from Alice", and you didn't answer anything. If I was Alice, I would expect an answer before talking. In short: I don't know anything about the communcation protocol. Is Alice supposed to send more lines than "Hello from Alice"?

Comment: I've been told that the chat robot can converse, but I'm starting to doubt that. I've contacted the server admin but I haven't received an answer yet. Thanks for your help though, at least I know my code should be correct.

Comment: Re-read my comment: conversation != monologue. You read what Alice sends, but you never send anything to Alice. Maybe Alice is expecting that YOU send her something before sending the next line.